# How to publish two versions of same app

Tags: android, google-play, versioning

I have a free app in Google store with ads.
I have received requests from users for a paid, ad-free version.
When I first uploaded the app to Google Play Store, it stated that if the app was free now it could never be changed.

My question is: Is it possible to have a paid and unpaid version of the same app on Google Play Store?

Comment: "it stated that if the app was free now it could never be changed." -- there you go. You can't change it. Use an in-app purchase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can offer some in-app purchases, like activation key to unlock additional features or access additional content. You do not need to replace all classes to have two versions, it may be enough to flip some boolean inside depending on how do you currently want it to be.

Comment: Would  prefer the in app purchase to maybe turn adds off. New version sounds messey and user would lose database content of unpaid version. Is there an example code or tutorial available?

Answer (score 3):

Change the package name and name of your app in AndroidManifest. Then it will be treated as another app.

Comment: So would have to change all google/Facebook map keys and new production key?

Comment: I think you can use the same production key. If Facebook/google map keys depend on package name, then you can have to change them as well.

Comment: But to have both version (add and add free) u would need two seperate pacakge names, two sep apks and two production keys

Comment: If there is a databse with use entries in the unpai version, would the data be lost if a paid ver (diff package name etc) was downloaded?

Comment: No, data wouldn't be lost, but it wouldn't be available in the newly downloaded paid version - as it would be treated as an entirely new app.